# How to do a custom redirection on AllAuth Social Account Signup

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have tried to do the following, but neither redirect nor render works:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter, get_account_adapter
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

from django.shortcuts import render

class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def __init__(self, request=None):
        DefaultSocialAccountAdapter.__init__(self, request)

    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        """
        Saves a newly signed up social login. In case of auto-signup,
        the signup form is not available.
        """
        print('saving user')
        u = sociallogin.user
        u.set_unusable_password()
        if form:
            get_account_adapter().save_user(request, u, form)
        else:
            get_account_adapter().populate_username(request, u)
        sociallogin.save(request)
        print('right before redirect')
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html',
                      context={'title': 'Edit Profile', 'register_update': 'Update'})
```

Only an `ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect('url'))` works, but then it redirects to the login page.
Signals does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Oops...I've found a solution to my own problem...

Just create a sign in processor view in your views.py, like so:

```
def sign_in_processor(request):
    user = request.user
    required = [#User Fields that were not filled up by the social provider on creation]
    for f in required:
        if not f:
            return redirect('profile_edit')
    return redirect('home')
```

`'profile_edit'` is a view based off a `UserChangeForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms` or its derivatives.

Comment: Im open to any better solutions!!